# In wordpress, css change in the_content()

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm new for WordPress. I'm using `the_content()` to get image and posted text. I need to change the CSS in Text of post.

Html coding is,

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p> 
        <a href="http://.../?attachment_id=34#main" rel="attachment wp-att-34">
            <img src="http://.../uploads/2013/03/1-1.jpg" alt="1-1" width="960" height="283" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-34">
        </a>
    </p>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adnenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt Cras dapibus.
    </p>
</div>
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done in several ways

1. When you create a new post, add some html element to the text and assign the a class to it and style that class in your style.css
2. Use inline style.
3. Or simply just put new rule in css file

   .entry-content p{
       // your style here
   }

Comment: this is not purely CSS related. This all method are no use. Know WordPress?

Comment: "you want to style your post" thats all what i understand from your question... and yes i know wordpress.

Comment: This looks about right to me too, given the extremely limited information provided in the question.

Comment: If any chance to create as dynamically?